# How to make a (not all) tree item always expanded in a QTreeView?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qtreeview

How can I make a (not all) tree item always expanded in a QTreeView? I cannot find a good way to do it.

Comment: Did you find a solution back then?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the `itemsExpandable` property to false by calling `setItemsExpandable(false)`. This property holds whether the user can expand and collapse items interactively. Once the property is set to false, any items expanded by you will not be possible to collapse by the user.

Comment: Does this mean all the items cannot be expanded or shrunken by users? I only want some items (such as top-level items) not be shrunken by users.

Comment: That's the kind of information you should offer when you ask the question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
tree_item.setExpanded(true)
tree_item.setDisabled(true)
```

I have not tested it but according to the docs it should work.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#setDisabled

Comment: Also consider to call `setExpanded(true)` [after adding](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#setExpanded) the item to `QTreeWidget`.